# How to replace cell info in excel conditionaly with another cell info from another sheet regarding to another cell value

Tags: excel

I have two sheet of excel
the first one has a reference number with price and the second one has a reference number with updated price.
What am willing to do is to see the match refno from the sheet2 with the sheet1 then replace the price in the sheet1 with the updated price from the sheet2 according to the Refno.
Any idea of how to do that in excel please.

```
Sheet1
Refno     Price
1001       50
10002      80
10003      70
10004      60
```

```
Sheet2
Refno     Updated Price
1001       65
10002      85
```

Comment: Use vba, compare values, replace as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RefNo is in column A of Sheet1, and Sheet1 B2 is the 1st cell that need the formula..

in B2, put `=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))` then drag downwards. I think that should do it..